# Is anything required to get a Quartz callback besides registering for it?

Tags: macos, quartz-graphics

I'm trying to use `CGDisplayRegisterReconfigurationCallback` to get display reconfiguration events in Quartz on Mac OS X.  Here's the super-simple code:

```
void CB(CGDirectDisplayID display,
        CGDisplayChangeSummaryFlags flags,
        void *userInfo) {
    std::cout << "In callback!" << std::endl;
}

int main (int argc, char * const argv[]) {
    std::cout << CGDisplayRegisterReconfigurationCallback(CB, NULL) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Registered callback, sleeping..." << std::endl;
    sleep(10000000);
    return 0;
}
```

However, the callback isn't getting called when I plug/unplug monitors, etc.  `CGDisplayRegisterReconfigurationCallback` returns success.

'new to os x development' would be an overstatement of my background knowledge here.  Do I need to instantiate something like a quartz event loop to get callbacks to work?

Answer (score 0):

You need some kind of a run loop.  A standard Cocoa or Carbon app has this as part of the normal event processing.  I guess the most bare-bones way would use CFRunLoopRun.