# Getting notification of screen resolution changes on Mac

Tags: macos, notifications

I want to register for screen resolution changes on the Mac.  I have a c++ library that I use to listen for Power Notification events as well has hotplug events using IOKit but I'm not finding anything about how to register for resolution changes.  I would like to do this without Cocoa if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4921817/get-screen-resolution-programaticaly-in-os-x) may help you.

For a more in-depth article, read here: [Getting Information About Displays](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/QuartzDisplayServicesConceptual/Articles/DisplayInfo.html)

Comment: Thank you MrGomez.  For power notification and hotplug events, I create a run loop source reference and add it to the current run loop.  Do you have any insight into how I add CGDisplayRegisterReconfigurationCallback(...) as a run loop source?

Comment: @wheels53 I admit, I'm not a domain expert. But, I found [this terse example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958281/is-anything-required-to-get-a-quartz-callback-besides-registering-for-it), which pointed me to [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8590546/cfrunlooprun-vs-nsrunloop-run) on how to set up a `CFRunLoopRun`. Your quandary [seems to be a shared one](http://lists.apple.com/archives/quartz-dev/2007/Jan/msg00026.html), in any event!